# Reassigning su command

Tags: su

I accidentally linked my "su" command to Sublime Text binary (that's what you get when you trust hitting tab without looking...)
Now, "su" just opens a SublimeTExt session.
Does anybody know how can I revert to the previous version and point "su" to what it is supposed to be pointing at?
Thank you!

EDIT: the command that was accidentaly issued was

```
sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/su
```

Comment: How did u do that?!

Comment: remove the link!

Comment: Please insert these informations in your quest to clarify it more

Comment: I editted to add he issued command. Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original `su` is in `/bin/su`, so just delete your link:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/su
```

Check `which su` if it's back to `/bin/su`

There a priority in executable paths, see:

```
echo $PATH
```

`/usr/bin` comes before `/bin`, So your link will be executed first. But to learn create that link again and run `which su` you will get `/usr/bin/su`.

Well, all $PATH can hold executable itself or its link. So most of those paths hold a mixture, give `ls -l /usr/bin` a try (I cut long results) :

```
total 925272
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       39552 Dec 18 14:36 [
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           8 Dec 21 15:14 2to3 -> 2to3-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          96 Jan 12 10:12 2to3-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          96 Jan 27 17:21 2to3-3.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          96 Jan 27 17:23 2to3-3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root        5655 Jan  7 12:12 404main
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       10320 Feb  7  2013 411toppm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          39 Feb 17  2012 7z
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          40 Feb 17  2012 7za
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          40 Feb 17  2012 7zr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      106584 Jan 15 06:49 a2p
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          52 Jan 25 00:22 a2ping -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/a2ping/a2ping.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         883 Apr 30  2007 a5booklet
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          54 Jan 25 00:22 a5toa4 -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/pfarrei/a5toa4.tlu
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       10328 Apr 28  2009 aa3d
```

Links are clear now, 3 links, others are files:

- `l` in the beginning of `lrwxrwxrwx` (l link, d directory, - normal file, c char device).
- `->` point to the target file.

Comment: Yes that solved it. 
So, i guess /usr/bin is only links. Good to know. Thank you!

Comment: No, you can create links in almost all places. But you create it there `/usr/bin/su` in your `ln` command

Comment: Yes of course. I meant that /usr/bin is meant to host links and not the binaries.

Comment: Yes, in your case for your *link* . No, if you mean, `/usr/bin` hosts *links* only (as general rule). I updated my answer, Let me know if I should clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

If you used aliases to do it, as people in comments are asking you, you can temporally avoid the alias by tiping:

```
\su <restofthecommandhere>
```

The "\" tells bash to use the real command, ignoring the alias. Then, you can edit your .bashrc and remove the line making reference to this alias:

```
gedit $HOME/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used an alias, the way to remove it is as follows:

1. Temporarily remove it

   ```
   unalias su
   ```
2. To permanently remove it, delete it from your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` file.

Most likely you didn't link `su` to sublime text binary because doing that would have required `sudo` privileges. So just check if the first solution in the list works. If it works then and the problem reappears again later, you need to follow instruction 2.